# ElasticSearch Aggregation Missing Data

Tags: elasticsearch

On elastic search, when I run an aggregation query it only runs it on one index. How do I get it to run on multiple indicies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a [multi-index search](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-multi-index-type).

As an example, I created a couple of indexes (implicitly) by bulk indexing some data:

```
POST /_bulk
{ "index": {"_index": "test_index", "_type":"doc"}}
{ "name": "Brown foxes"}
{ "index": {"_index": "test_index_2", "_type":"doc"}}
{ "name": "Yellow furballs" }
{ "index": {"_index": "test_index", "_type":"doc"}}
{ "name": "my discovery" }
{ "index": {"_index": "test_index_2", "_type":"doc"}}
{ "name": "myself is fun" }
{ "index": {"_index": "test_index", "_type":"doc"}}
{ "name": ["foxy", "foo"]    }
{ "index": {"_index": "test_index_2", "_type":"doc"}}
{ "name": ["foo bar", "baz"] }
```

Then I can run an aggregation on both indexes:

```
POST /test_index,test_index_2/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "name_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get back all the terms from both:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "successful": 10,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "name_terms": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "foo",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "bar",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "baz",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "brown",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "discovery",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "foxes",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "foxy",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "fun",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "furballs",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "is",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e053a0c6c5453eae68d7b7ff2ff12588669b046e

Comment: Hmm, so if I have the similar fields in two different indexes and the query seems to be only returning data from one index , what could that mean?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your mappings, a little representative data, and your query. Or, preferably, a simplification that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Nevermind, it was the mappings. Thanks anyway. And i'll mark this as complete